# how to compute for a time-value that is within a fixed time-range in 24-hour format?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working in a time-keeping proposal that'll automatically compute hours rendered exceeding the original shift ( Over-Time ), and Hours with Night Differential ( it starts at 22:00 and ends at 7:00 the following day ) and the combination of the 2 ( OT with Night Differential ). Please refer to my example for clarifications:

[image]

Time In is at H11* 
Time Out is at I11*
OT is at K11*
Night Differential is at M11*
What I want as an output in L11* is the hours wherein both OT and Night Differential is at play.

Say Employee1 comes in at 16:00 with a supposed time-out at 1:00 the following day, that would mean he'd be entitled to a 3 Hour Night-Differential, but he rendered an hour of Over-time so he now has 4 Hour Night Diff, 1 of which is under OT. The result of L11 should be 1 hour of both OT and Night Diff. Do you have any suggestion as to how the formula should be? I've been stuck for days now, I appreciate every advice you can give me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My initial idea is to increment a counter whenever the Employee1 renders OT for more than 30 minutes thus the title of my query. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: This might be easier to follow if you could share a sample file or at least a screenshot. Post a screenshot and we can make it appear. Better yet, share a file with an ad-free file sharing service like Dropbox or Onedrive and post a link. then explain in context.

Comment: Hi  teylyn, this is my proposed template. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/821x263q90/924/tAmVjq.png

Comment: please edit your question and add details there. Don't post details in comments. As a new user you may want to take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: Do you want it as VBA-code or Excel formula?

Comment: @Fansher formula if possible. The file is getting too big